# Фрагментация в СУБД

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

БД- это здоровенный файл, где СУБД заранее резервирует место под объекты и автоматически расширяет его на некоторый % при подходе к размерам.

Так вот у меня вопрос:

Влияют ли операции в одной таблице на ускорение фрагментации в другой таблице?

Ну скажем:
Сначала создали Таблицу 1 и добавили в нее 100500 записей, а потом создали таблицу 2 и добавили в нее 100500 записей.

Сейчас, никакой фрагментации быть точно не должно, так как данные записывались последовательно.

Но что будет, если мы грохнем данные из первой таблицы и добавим новые данные во вторую таблицу? Будут ли они фрагментированными или СУБД не обратит внимание на освободившееся место в начале файла и будет писать в конец?

Если рассматривать фрагментацию HDD, то диск пишет данные в то место, куда может=> не оптимизируя нахождение данных рядом друг с другом.

Фрагментация СУБД происходит по тому же принципу, как фрагментация на HDD или субд сама автоматически разруливает все это и в примере выше, данные не будут фрагментированными?

Comment: `БД- это здоровенный файл` хм интересно.

Comment: Думаю, что сначала заполнится уже выделенный экстент, а потом данные второй таблицы будут записываться куда придётся (возможно ближе к началу файла). Вообще это легко проверить. При добавлении данных скорее всего в приоритете быстрота insert-а, а не будущих select-ов.

Answer (score 1):

Базы данных SQL Server представляют собой большие файлы базы данных и журналов, 
для которых во время создания резервируется некоторый размер. 
Если при создании этих файлов на диске есть непрерывный, не занятый и достаточный по размеру отрезок, они не будут фрагментированы. Но если доступное свободное место не является непрерывным, то уже изначально база данных и журналы будут фрагментированы. 
Даже если первоначально база данных и журналы не фрагментированы, после их создания, они почти наверняка станут фрагментированными, поскольку база данных все время растет. Например, если Вы устанавливаете первоначальный размер базы данных равным 100 МБ, а файл журнала 10 МБ, и установили следующие параметры автоматического прироста файлов: до 5Гб файл данных и до 100 МБ файл журнала, внешняя фрагментация может быть большой. 
Каждый раз, когда файлы данных или журналов автоматически увеличиваются, появляется угроза фрагментации.

И так фрагментацию можно разделить на внешнюю и внутреннею.